# How to get Jenkins to --fail-fast on Maven 2 builds?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-2, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to build a multi-module Maven project using Jenkins.

When I build the same project on the **command-line** using the **same environment** (variables/settings.xml/user) as Jenkins does, test failures cause the build to fail immediately:

```
Failed tests:
  testSomething(com.package_name.TestSomethingOrTheOther)

Tests run: .., Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.
...
# Build fails immediately
```

Where-as when building in **Jenkins**:

```
Failed tests:
  testSomething(com.package_name.TestSomethingOrTheOther)

Tests run: .., Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[ERROR] There are test failures.
...
# Build continues to other modules
...
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] parent ................................................ SUCCESS [.....s]
[INFO] module-that-failed .................................... SUCCESS [.....s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The build states that all modules and parent are **SUCCESS**-ful, when in reality, these should be failures.

**How do I get Jenkins to enforce fail-fast in maven builds as maven does in the command-line?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same maven goals in Jenkins as what you are using locally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jenkins ignores test failures by default, and then marks the build as unstable if they were any.

The parameter that controls that is: testFailureIgnore (see [surefire plugin doc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html))

I've never tried that, but I would attempt to override that setting on the jenkins job configuration:

-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false

Comment: Yup.  Just to be clear, you can set the explicit maven command : for example "clean package -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false" , in the "Goals and Options" jenkins section in the Configure window for your build.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `MAVEN_OPTS` if you click on *Advanced* button in the *Build* section.