# Maven Multi Module child test fails, but, all modules build.

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins, maven-2

I have maven setup in my Spring Framework project and I have a test deliberatly failing to test my build failure (running `maven test`). My Spring Project is configured with Maven Multi Module. That POM xml below is my parent POM. The test is failing in a child POM however `maven install` builds all the projects.

Here is my parent maven plugin configuration:

```
     <build>
    <finalName>cointraders-website</finalName>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Child maven pom:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                     <id>unit-tests</id>
                      <phase>unit-test</phase>
                      <goals>
                         <goal>test</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*UnitTest.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And the console log on success:

```
 [INFO] parent-project .................................... SUCCESS [  1.327 s]
 [INFO] xxxxx-data .................................. SUCCESS [01:41 min]
 [INFO] xxxxx-commandline ........................... SUCCESS [  2.597 s]
 [INFO] xxxxx-api ................................... SUCCESS [ 54.613 s]
```

The test failure happens in xxxxx-data child project:

```
 Tests run: 204, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10421115/2915087

Comment: @MobilePetroleum sorry that does not help as testFailureIgnore defaults to false.

Comment: There is no unit-test phase